# How mount IR gas detector sensor for outdoor use

Tags: sensor, surface-mount, infrared, outdoors

I'm in search of a Gas detector sensor for outdoor use and I've found this [sensor](https://www.mouser.it/new/pyreos/pyreos-thin-film-pyroelectric-sensors/#Bullet-1).
My only concern is how do I mount it for outdoor use as, on the datasheet, there's no information about the mounting.
Do you think I need to put inside some sort of enclosure or can I mount it with the head of the sensor in direct contact with the outside air?

Comment: Avoid Rain might be sensible

Comment: so you suggest to mount everything inside an enclosure and let the air to go inside via, let's say, a protected hole on the side as this example? [link](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/CO-NO-NO2-O3-Co2-PM2_60535743953.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I've found out is to have emitter and sensor inside an enclosure. The enclosure will have a protected hole so environment air can be detected without damaging the sensors.

I took an example from [here](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/CO-NO-NO2-O3-Co2-PM2_60535743953.html)